How to represent fraction text value like ⅑ but with a straight divider like given in the image?
I am using fabric js textbox and on a click of a button a fraction string gets added to the textbox, Currently as a workaround I'm showing fractions like ⅑ but I have to represent the fractions with a straight divider as shown in the image. Is there any way I can do this?

